# @Inject PersonDao is null in @FacesConverter class

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, converters, cdi

I am trying to get from `selectOneMenu` an object that has fields such as first name, last name and so on.  This is my form:

```
<h:form>

<p:outputLabel value="Persons: " />
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{personBean.person}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Person" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true"/>
    <f:selectItems itemLabel="#{person.firstName}" itemValue="#{person}" var="person" value="#{personBean.persons}" />

</p:selectOneMenu>
<br /><br />
<p:commandButton value="Submit"
    action="#{personBean.showSomething()}" icon="ui-icon-check" />
```

I don't understand.. where am i going wrong? How can i get that object? 
I've been trying for a few days but i haven't managed to fix this problem...
I tried using a `Converter` but i kept getting NPEs.

**EDIT**
This is my converter:(I am trying to get the object from my postgres db with the help of my DAO)

```
@Named
@FacesConverter(forClass=Person.class)
public class PersonConverter implements Converter {

    @Inject
    private PersonDao personDao;

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent component, String submittedValue) {
        if (submittedValue == null || submittedValue.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        try {
            Person p = personDao.findById(Long.valueOf(submittedValue));
            return p;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(submittedValue + " is not a valid Person ID"), e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, Object arg2) {
        if (arg2 == null) {
            return "";
        }

        if (arg2 instanceof Person) {
            return String.valueOf(((Person) arg2).getId());
        } else {
            throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(arg2 + " is not a valid Person"));
        }
    }

}
```

This is where i get a NPE `Person p = personDao.findById(Long.valueOf(submittedValue));` 
The find() method works anywhere else...
When i used the debugger i noticed that personDao is null. How can i fix this?

Comment: Only when i was using the converter. When not, `personBean.showInfo()` was not even called so it didn't return anything.

Comment: please add more information. like your stacktrace where you get your NPE. Also, shouldn't itemValue be #{person}? instead of the #{person.firstName}?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

- In the page:

  ```
          <p:selectOneMenu value="#{personBean.person}">
              <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Person" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true"/>
              <f:selectItems itemLabel="#{person.firstName}" itemValue="#{person}" var="person" value="#{personBean.persons}" />
              <f:converter binding="#{personConverter}" />
              <f:attribute name="attrpersons" value="#{personBean.persons}" />                    
          </p:selectOneMenu>
  ```
- In the Person bean:

  You must implement toString and equals methods.
- And finally you have to add the converter class:

  ```
  @Named
  public class PersonConverter implements Converter{

      public PersonConverter(){}

      @Override
        public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, String submittedValue) {
            List<Person> persons = (List<Person>)component.getAttributes().get("attrpersons");
          if (submittedValue.trim().equals("")) {
              return null;
          } else {
              Iterator<Person> it = persons.iterator();
              while(it.hasNext()){
                  Person p = it.next();
                  if(p.toString().equals(submittedValue))
                      return p;                
              }
          }
          return null;
      }

      @Override
      public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, Object value) {
          if (value == null) {
              return "";
          } else {
              return value.toString();
          }
      }
  }
  ```